# Крипто про. Видимая подпись PDF

Tags: c#, rsa, криптопро

Небольшая проблема с созданием ЭЦП подписи по Госту с использование сертификата

вот код

```
static public class Sign
{        
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string document = "x.pdf"; 
        string certificate_dn = "nas"; 


        // Находим секретный ключ по сертификату в хранилище MY 
        X509Store store = new X509Store("My", StoreLocation.CurrentUser); 
        store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly | OpenFlags.ReadOnly); 
        X509Certificate2Collection found = store.Certificates.Find( 
        X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, certificate_dn, true); 


        X509Certificate2 certificate = found[0]; 

        Gost3410CryptoServiceProvider cert_key = certificate.PrivateKey as Gost3410CryptoServiceProvider; 
        if (null != cert_key) 
        { 
            var cspParameters = new CspParameters(); 
            //копируем параметры csp из исходного контекста сертификата 
            cspParameters.KeyContainerName = cert_key.CspKeyContainerInfo.KeyContainerName; 
            cspParameters.ProviderType = cert_key.CspKeyContainerInfo.ProviderType; 
            cspParameters.ProviderName = cert_key.CspKeyContainerInfo.ProviderName; 
            cspParameters.Flags = cert_key.CspKeyContainerInfo.MachineKeyStore 
            ? (CspProviderFlags.UseExistingKey | CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore) 
            : (CspProviderFlags.UseExistingKey); 
            cspParameters.KeyPassword = new SecureString(); 
            foreach (var c in "1") 
            { 
                cspParameters.KeyPassword.AppendChar(c); 
            } 
            //создаем новый контекст сертификат, поскольку исходный открыт readonly 
            certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificate.RawData); 
            //задаем криптопровайдер с установленным паролем 
            certificate.PrivateKey = new Gost3410CryptoServiceProvider(cspParameters); 
        } 


        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(document); 
        PdfStamper st = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, new FileStream(document + "_signed.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write), '\0'); 
        PdfSignatureAppearance sap = st.SignatureAppearance; 

        // Загружаем сертификат в объект iTextSharp 
        X509CertificateParser parser = new X509CertificateParser(); 
        Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[] chain = new Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[]
        { 
            parser.ReadCertificate(certificate.RawData) 
        }; 

        sap.Certificate = parser.ReadCertificate(certificate.RawData); 
        sap.Reason = "Neosign";

        sap.Location = "city"; 
        sap.Acro6Layers = true; 


        //sap.Render = PdfSignatureAppearance.SignatureRender.NameAndDescription; 

        sap.SignDate = DateTime.Now; 

        // Выбираем подходящий тип фильтра 
        PdfName filterName = new PdfName("CryptoPro PDF"); 

        // Создаем подпись 
        PdfSignature signature = new PdfSignature(filterName, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED); 

        signature.Date = new PdfDate(sap.SignDate); 
        signature.Name = certificate_dn; 
        signature.Reason = sap.Reason ?? "No reason"; 
        signature.Location = sap.Location ?? "No location"; 
        sap.CryptoDictionary = signature; 

        int intCSize = 4000;
        Dictionary<PdfName, int> hashtable = new Dictionary<PdfName, int>();
        hashtable.Add(PdfName.CONTENTS, intCSize * 2 + 2);

        sap.PreClose(hashtable); 

        Stream s = sap.GetRangeStream(); 

        MemoryStream ss = new MemoryStream(); 

        int read = 0; 
        byte[] buff = new byte[8192]; 

        while ((read = s.Read(buff, 0, 8192)) > 0) 
        { 
            ss.Write(buff, 0, read); 
        } 


        // Вычисляем подпись 
        ContentInfo contentInfo = new ContentInfo(ss.ToArray()); 
        SignedCms signedCms = new SignedCms(contentInfo, true); 
        CmsSigner cmsSigner = new CmsSigner(certificate); 
        signedCms.ComputeSignature(cmsSigner, false); 
        byte[] pk = signedCms.Encode(); 


        // Помещаем подпись в документ 
        byte[] outc = new byte[intCSize]; 
        PdfDictionary dic2 = new PdfDictionary(); 

        Array.Copy(pk, 0, outc, 0, pk.Length); 
        dic2.Put(PdfName.CONTENTS, new PdfString(outc).SetHexWriting(true)); 


        sap.SetVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(4, 4, 4, 4), 1, "sign");



        var H = sap.Certificate.SigAlgName;
        IExternalSignature externalSignature = new X509Certificate2Signature(certificate, H); 
        MakeSignature.SignDetached(sap, externalSignature, chain, null, null, null, 0, CryptoStandard.CADES); 

        sap.Close(dic2); 

        Console.WriteLine("Document {0} success sign om key {1} => {2}.", 
        document, certificate.Subject, document + "_signed.pdf"); 
        Console.ReadKey(); 
    }
}
```

Вот скрин ошибка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что за key  не понятно
Кто имел дело с подобным как пофиксить.
 Если брать сертификат не по Госту то все ок. 
SDK от крипто про стоит. Невидимая подпись этим же кодом ставится.

```
using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Security;
   using System.Security.Cryptography;
   using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
   using iTextSharp.text;

    //#if PDF_SIGNATURE_ENABLED
    namespace Simple35.Pdf
    {
        using CryptoPro.Sharpei;
        using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
        using iTextSharp.text.pdf.security;
        using Org.BouncyCastle.X509;
        using System.IO;
        using System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs;
        public class Program
        {
            /// code
        }
    }
```

Comment: с сайта скачена не давно. думаю должна 2012 поддерживатьт

Comment: куда конекретно

Comment: и какое надо добавить

Comment: Угу... key - это что-то недозаполненное во внутренних структурах подписи или документа, пока еще не до конца понял что и где именно. Вообще у вас очень странный порядок формирования штампа, по идее визуализация и формирование "пустышки" должны происходить одновременно и уже после этого получение и вставка подписи в штамп. Может в этом дело, пока не уверен.

Answer (score 0):

Строки

```
 var H = sap.Certificate.SigAlgName;
 IExternalSignature externalSignature = new X509Certificate2Signature(certificate, H); 
 MakeSignature.SignDetached(sap, externalSignature, chain, null, null, null, 0, CryptoStandard.CADES);
```

лишнии, достаточно задать текст или картинку:

```
 sap.Image = Image.GetInstance(@"D:\sign.png");;
 sap.Layer2Font = new Font(Font.FontFamily.COURIER);
 sap.Layer2Text = "Signed";
 sap.SetVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(250, 250, 380, 300), 1, "Signature");
```